# Minecraft Server restart after action

Tags: server, minecraft

I am trying to code a LoL plugin for my MC-server and I need everytime, to restart the server when the game ends. So if the last player dies or something the server needs to restart, to set everything on default. My problem is, I can't get the line of code that restarts the server. I hope you can help as fast as possible

Comment: I found it out: `Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(). "restart");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I would do is [assuming you are using spigot], go to your spigot.yml file and change the "restart script" line to whatever your start.bat/sh file is called. Then, when someone dies use `Bukkit.getConsoleSender().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "restart");`